# Variable not assigning actual value while writing to $GITHUB_ENV

Tags: linux, bash, shell, github-actions, sh

I have a script which `greps` for particular patterns and update them.
I also need the count of number of files that are updated.
I need to write that count to $GITHUB_ENV

During increment, the variable is assigning correct value. But when writing it to $GITHUB_ENV, it is writing initial value of the variable.

```
counter=0
grep -ril "search_pattern" ${directory_path%/} | while IFS= read -r file; do
  counter=$((counter + 1))
  echo "Script file: $file"
done
echo "COUNTER=$counter" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

While executing the last line - `echo`, it's always giving `0` for `$counter` even though I see the `$counter` getting updated inside the loop.

I used `set -x` to see it the variable is getting updated inside the loop. and it is updating.

Comment: Your while loop is executed by a child process and hence uses its own value for `counter`. So don't pipe the output of `grep` into your loop.

Comment: Don't tag your question by _bash_ and by _sh_, but make up your mind, which shell language you are going to use - in particular since a good solution of your question depends on what shell you are writing the code in.